# Check if a quad is fully covered by a set of others

Tags: math, occlusion

I am doing a lot of voxel game development and I am optimizing the light engine. The idea is, that I can check if light can enter a block or not.

To break down the question to the minimal, here it is:

I got a set of quads. Now I need to check if the target quad is completely (i.e. no light can shine through) covered by the set.

Examples:

- `[(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)]` -> `true`
- `[(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5)]` -> `false`
- `[(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5)`, `(0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0)]` -> `true`

How do I solve it? Performance is not the biggest concern here, the data is pre calculated.

I tried calculating the surface area and adding them together, but that has the flaw of floating point error and even more important: What if quads are overlapping? Then that breaks.

I also tried iterating and checking if it exceeds the bounding box, like `quad.min.x < targetMinX || quad.min.x > targetMaxX || …` but that fails in some cases.